# Spyder - code change does not reflect on the browser

Tags: python, spyder, justpy

Executing a program in Python using the Spyder IDE (4.2.5).
Created a webapp using the below

````
```import justpy as jp
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
def app():
    wp=jp.QuasarPage()
    h1=jp.Div(text='Analysis of Course Reviews',a=wp,classes='text-h1 text-center')
    p1=jp.Div(text='Graphs that represent Course Reviews',a=wp)
    return wp

jp.justpy(app)```
````

Webapp created on the browser uses the old code(one that was executed the first time) - it does not refresh based on the latest code until I restart the kernel.

**Note: I have been interrupting the current run of the program and rerunning the code whenever I make any changes**

Is there a workaround to restarting the kernel everytime I change the code?

Comment: There is a justpy issue asking for a feature that would allow this see https://github.com/justpy-org/justpy/issues/236

Answer (score 0):

Try doing hard reload, using `Crtl + Shift + R`